# any way to know the real time status of speaker is it playing any sound through cli?

Tags: audio, hardware, speakers

Recently i want to create a service on my pi which additional logic, one service needs to be stopped when the speaker is playing any sound. Any way i can get the status like a system log file about whether the speaker is being used?

Answer (score 1):

if you use ALSA then this command should help you:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/pcm*p/sub*/hw_params
```

when nothing is playing the output is "closed"
but when something is played it shows i.e. like this:

```
 22:21:52  pi@sabaj-d5:~ $  cat /proc/asound/card*/pcm*p/sub*/hw_params
```

access: MMAP_INTERLEAVED
format: S32_LE
subformat: STD
channels: 2
rate: 44100 (44100/1)
period_size: 441
buffer_size: 1764
22:21:57  pi@sabaj-d5:~ $